# nodejs- 'failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

I was following a youtube tutorial on docker-compose https://youtu.be/hP77Rua1E0c

when I try to run this code as it is It show error as

```
failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to mongo:27017 timed out]'
```

I am running this file on docker-compose
[github repo](https://github.com/bradtraversy/docker-node-mongo)

this is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:enter image description here
  app:
    container_name: docker-node-mongo
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

I'm using **mongo** in the URL

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodb://mongo:27017/docker-node-mongo',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
```

I am using ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

I'm getting this error
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ck5D.png)
I am new to docker-compose, Please help me out.

Comment: check your ip address is whitelisted in mongodb network access panel

Comment: @Anilkumar is there a way to whitelist locally cause I'm not using mongodb atlas here